# Progressive abstract class extension in Java pattern

Tags: java, oop

Suppose I have an abstract class that defines an endpoint as such, and a class that overrides said endpoint and whose purpose is to wrap this endpoint in a try catch for example.

```java
public abstract class Endpoint {
  public abstract void handle(Request req, Response res);
}
```

```java
public abstract class ErrableEndpoint {
  public void handle(Request req, Response res){
    try {
       handleRequest(req, res);
    } catch(Exception e){
      // handle the error in some way
    }
  }

  public abstract void handleRequest(Request req, Response res);
}
```

```java
public class UserEndpoint extends ErrableEndpoint {
  public void handleRequest(Request req, Response res){ 
    // Do things which might throw an error.
  } 
}
```

Now, if I extend this class further, using still abstract classes to allow for a creation of a hierarchy, I end up renaming methods again, and again, and again.

There are currently 2 things I've considered.

1. Using interfaces - This is currently outside of the realm of possibility due to the fact that I have state within the endpoint which is passed through a constructor. I'm also not looking for lambda capability, so it's not an issue.
2. Calling .super() - I'm looking to avoid this, as I'm working on a framework-oriented project, where I would like the people who use it to not have to call super, and where they should be able to mindlessly extend. Requiring super by convention could lead to weird buggy behavior if the user forgets to call it. This is avoided with the method renaming pattern I'm currently using.

Essentially, I'm looking for a way to continuously add functionality on top of the same method, without having to constantly rename it on each extension.

Comment: _"Essentially, I'm looking for a way..."_ you do not provide any reason to not use `super` (the canonical way).

Comment: I mentioned in the things I've considered that I'd like to avoid super, since it can lead to weird behaviour is the user forgets to call it. I'm wondering if there's some kind of way to progressively add functionality without having to rename the method. Especially considering, that, more often than not, the functionality I add will have the super method somewhere random.

Comment: If you do not override the method, the super is called, if you override the method, you **must** decide if you need call or not to the super, if you forgot that, you should look for another job.

Comment: I am sorry, but I haven't found a place where you renamed methods. Where did you rename your methods?  And you can not to call `super()` and just `override` your method.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the kind of further extension that you need?